# how to change ringer mode to (Silent or Vibrate) mode

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ipod

I am creating one app in which i want to detect that iphone is on silent mode or not.if not then how to change ringer mode to  (Silent or Vibrate) mode .

Comment: You are trying to access the private API, i think your app might get rejected.

Comment: How is it possible to change the ringer mode from the software side? Isn't that controlled by the switch button on the side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by using **private API** but your app will be rejected by apple AppStore as per apple policy which doesn't allow private API ,so then if you still wanna do it then you could go for **Cydia** [Store](https://cydia.saurik.com/) to upload which is a store for rooted(jail broken) apple device's.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect that, some may say you can do by overriding some methods or using private API.

Be careful about overriding the silent mode switch and playing audio. Apple may not like you doing this, depending on the context; if they don't like it, you will fail app review.